# Summation variable order problem

Tags: summation

I was reading this [paper](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/12/8/10947/htm#FD15) in Computer Vision (You do not have to visit it unless you want that). I came across this formula (Eq. 15 in the paper):
[image]

Where:

- `T`,`M` are 2D same size matrices.
- `sign` is `N` -> `[-1,0,+1]` function.
- `N`,`i`,`j` are known.

**The question:**

I could not understand the summation order. I should start from the inner `sigma` (The one which its variable is `h`). If I did so, all `h`s inside the `sign` function will be replaced with numbers. Then I started to solve the outer `sigma` (which has a variable `k` that starts from `h+1` !!) and that were I stopped and did not know what to do!

Is there something wrong with equation? How should I compute it?

I suspected that the order of the two `sigma`s is wrong and should be reversed but when I do so, I am getting no sense results in term of Computer Vision result.

Comment: The order has no effect. Even if you change the order the final result would be same.

Comment: @WiCK3DPOiSON It is correct! it is just summation.. stupid me! I am in doubt now that the whole equation is not correct since I am applying it on very simple input and the result is too far from correctness (or I have messed up things while implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the $h$s being replaced by numbers.  The pair of sums gives you all the terms with $j \le h \lt k \le j+N$, so you pick each pair of distinct numbers from $j$ to $j+N$ and check the sign of the corresponding $M$s.  You can do the sums in the other order if you make the ranges right so you get all the terms.  The way you have starts by selecting $k$ then lets $h$ range up from $j$ to $k-1$.   For each $k$ you have $+1$ for all the $M_{ih}$ that are less and $-1$ for all the $M_{ih}$ that are greater, then you add up over $k$ in the outer sum.  What this is computing is the number of $M$s that are in the right order according to their indices minus the number that are in reverse order.

Alternately we could choose $h$ first and then let $k$ range from $h+1$ to $j+N$.  This would give 
$$T_{ij}=\sum_{h=j}^{j+N-1}\sum_{k=h+1}^{j+N}\operatorname{sign}(M_{ik}-M_{ih})$$